# Groupby To Keep Combined Rows As 'Both'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm working on the following data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student': 'AA AA AA BB BB BB CC CC CC CC'.split(),
                   'grade': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']})

print(df)

  student   grade
0      AA     B
1      AA     B
2      AA     B
3      BB     A
4      BB     A
5      BB     B
6      CC     B
7      CC     B
8      CC     B
9      CC     B
```

I want to `groupby()` with `student` and combine. If the student has both the grades `A` and `B`, we'd mark as `both`, else we'd keep as the way the `grade` is.

I am trying the following code, but I'm not sure if it's optimal.

```
def get_both(data):
    Ptype = pd.crosstab(data['student'], data['grade'])
    data['grade'] = data['student'].map(Ptype.ne(0).dot(Ptype.columns))
    data.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    return data

get_both(df)

    student grade
0   AA       B
3   BB       AB
6   CC       B
```

**Desired Output**:

```
  student grade
0      AA     B
1      BB     both
2      CC     B
```

Is there any better way of getting the desired output? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
agg = df.groupby('student')['grade'].agg(['nunique', 'first'])
out = agg['first'].where(agg['nunique'].eq(1), 'both').reset_index(name='grade')
```

Output:

```
  student grade
0      AA     B
1      BB  both
2      CC     B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is slight different approach:

`groupby` column `student` then for `grade` column apply a lambda function to return `both` or the first grade depending on the condition

```py
(df
 .groupby(['student'], as_index=False)['grade']
 .apply(lambda x: 'both' if x.eq('A').any() and x.eq('B').any() else x.iloc[0])
 )
```

OUTPUT

```py
  student grade
0      AA     B
1      BB  both
2      CC     B
```